# Error compiling pytorch as an external library with Bazel - C++

Tags: c++, pytorch, bazel, bazel-cpp

I'm working on using Bazel to compile the C++ distribution of pytorch as an external library. I used the process provided in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288867/include-c-library-in-bazel-project) and was able to setup libtorch as a external library/remote repository. My file directory follows that of the one shown in the article. I verified the external library repository with
`bazel fetch @libtorch//:libtorch-lib`

My issue is that Bazel fails to compile when I include **torch/script.h** in my hello_world.cpp file yielding the error:

```
ERROR: /home/user/my_workspace/BUILD.bazel:3:10: Compiling hello_world.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command (from target //:hello_world) /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 45 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
stderr (/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/cc5484e3fb20813bb003f4dff235f23f/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/_tmp/actions/stderr-3) 12399173 exceeds maximum size of --experimental_ui_max_stdouterr_bytes=1048576 bytes; skipping
Target //:hello_world failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

Bazel recognizes it, but isn't able to finish its build process. My file directory is as follows

```
mediapipe
third_party
   BUILD.bazel
   cereal.BUILD.bazel
   libtorch.BUILD.bazel
BUILD.bazel
READ_ME.txt
WORKSPACE
hello_world.cc
```

Relevant code snippet from **WORKSPACE**

```
http_archive(
    name = "libtorch",
    sha256 = "137a842d1cf1e9196b419390133a1623ef92f8f84dc7a072f95ada684f394afd",
    urls = 
["https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-2.0.1%2Bcpu.zip"],
    build_file = "//third_party:libtorch.BUILD.bazel",
)
```

third_party/BUILD.bazel

```
exports_files = [
    "libtorch.BUILD.bazel",
]
```

third_party/libtorch.BUILD.bazel

```
# contents of //third_party/libtorch.BUILD.bazel
cc_library(
    name = "libtorch-lib",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.h", "**/*.hpp"]),
    includes = ["libtorch/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

BUILD.bazel

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")

cc_binary(
  name = "hello_world",
  deps = ["@com_google_absl//absl/strings", "@cereal//:cereal-lib", "@libtorch//:libtorch-lib"],
  srcs = ["hello_world.cc"],
)
```

I suspect I don't have everything needed in my BUILD file to properly compile the library, but I am looking for suggestions as to how I can test this theory and/or how I can bring everything I need to compile this pytorch library with Bazel.

These threads present similar issues that are, as of yet, unresolved.

[Bazel build error: gcc failed: error executing command](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bazel-build-error-gcc-failed-error-executing-command/149015/1)

[cc_library() import precompiled shared libraries to a temp directory caused error while loading shared libraries #10803](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10803)

Comment: Please inspect the file /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/cc5484e3fb20813bb003f4dff235f23f/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/_tmp/actions/stderr-3 and maybe include relevant parts in the question.